# Loss won't decrease on Siamese Network

Tags: python, opencv, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am very new to machine learning and I started implementing a Siamese network to check the similarity level on handwritten digits, training with MNIST dataset but i am having a serious loss problem.

### Network model

```
import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Lambda
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import keras.backend as K
import cv2
from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np
import random

def siameseNet(input_shape):
    input1 = Input(input_shape)
    input2 = Input(input_shape)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(50, (5,5), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(100, (3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(100, (3,3), activation='relu'))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(2048, activation='sigmoid'))

    input_model_1 = model(input1)
    input_model_2 = model(input2)
    distance_func = Lambda(lambda t: K.abs(t[0]-t[1]))
    distance_layer = distance_func([input_model_1, input_model_2])

    prediction = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(distance_layer)

    network = Model(inputs=[input1,input2],outputs=prediction)

    return network
```

### Training data

My `pairs` object is a `numpy` array with two arrays, containing the images on the same index, first half of the array are the image of the same category, second half different category.

`category` object is a simple array containing the same number of samples from the training set, first half of it beeing `0` to specify the Y value of beeing the same image, and second half is set to `1`.

Both `pairs` and `category` are populated in the following function:

```
INPUT_SHAPE = (28,28,1)

def loadData():
    (X_train, Y_train), _ = mnist.load_data()
    n_samples = 20000
    arrPairs = [np.zeros((n_samples, INPUT_SHAPE[0], INPUT_SHAPE[1],INPUT_SHAPE[2])) for i in range(2)]
    category = np.zeros((n_samples))
    category[n_samples//2:] = 1
    for i in range(n_samples): 
        if i%1000==0:
            print(i)

        cur_category = Y_train[i]

        img = random.choice(X_train[Y_train==cur_category]).reshape(28,28,1)
        _, img = cv2.threshold(img, .8, 1, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        arrPairs[0][i] = img.reshape(28,28,1)

        if category[i] == 1:
            img = random.choice(X_train[Y_train!=cur_category])
        else:
            img = random.choice(X_train[Y_train==cur_category])
        _, img = cv2.threshold(img, .8, 1, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        arrPairs[1][i] = img.reshape(28,28,1)
    arrPairs[0] = arrPairs[0]/255
    return arrPairs, category
```

### Training results

```
pairs, category = loadData()
model = siameseNet(INPUT_SHAPE)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0005),loss="binary_crossentropy")
model.fit(pairs, category,  epochs=5, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)

Train on 16000 samples, validate on 4000 samples
Epoch 1/5
16000/16000 [==============================] - 6s 353us/step - loss: 0.6660 - val_loss: 0.9474
Epoch 2/5
16000/16000 [==============================] - 5s 287us/step - loss: 0.6628 - val_loss: 0.9335
Epoch 3/5
16000/16000 [==============================] - 5s 287us/step - loss: 0.6627 - val_loss: 0.8487
Epoch 4/5
16000/16000 [==============================] - 5s 287us/step - loss: 0.6625 - val_loss: 0.9954
Epoch 5/5
16000/16000 [==============================] - 5s 288us/step - loss: 0.6616 - val_loss: 0.9133
```

But no matter what I try, the loss won't decrease, thus, predicting incorrectly.

I tried changing the activations, increasing and decreasing the network complexity (adding and removing layers, as well as increasing and decreasing the `Conv2D` parameters), but none of that worked, so i'm guessing it is an architectural problem that I am missing

**Update:**
Lines used for testing:

```
test_pairs = [np.zeros((2, INPUT_SHAPE[0], INPUT_SHAPE[1],INPUT_SHAPE[2])) for i in range(2)]
test_pairs[0][0] = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('test1_samenumber.png'), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY).reshape(28,28,1); 
test_pairs[1][0] = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('test2_samenumber.png'), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY).reshape(28,28,1);

pred = model.predict(test_pairs)
print(pred)
```

Which outputed:

```
[[0.32230237]
 [0.44603676]]
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @rayryeng, I indeed forgot. I applied the normalization and the losst went from 0.60 to 0.02. The loss problem was caused by it. But for some odd reason, the network still wrongly classifies the images, as I took two images of the same category and the probability of beeing the same was 33%, while two different images got the probability of beeing the same of 99%, any idea why?

Comment: I took a look at the unique values in your data.  There are only 0s and 1s, so actually we would need to remove the normalization.  This is probably due to you thresholding the digits so that there are only values that are 0 and 1.  I have a colab instance running and I'm going to test this out before getting back to you.

Comment: OK, so I've removed the unnecessary normalization and it seems that the loss is going down.  I'm going to wait until it finishes training before I test out the predictions.  I've also taken the liberty in making your code reproducible.  There were certain function calls and packages missing that would prevent anyone from getting this to run out of box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have unnecessary normalization when loading in your data.  Specifically, for the first pair of images, you are dividing by 255 when that isn't required.  After you threshold with `cv2.threshold`, the output values are inherently 0 or 1, so further dividing by 255 makes the dynamic range smaller than the second pair of images which may cause a problem in learning how to differentiate between two images.  I've removed this normalization by commenting out the `arrPairs[0] = arrPairs[0] / 255` statement.

After I trained your network, I ran through each of the pairs and examined the output prediction.  Essentially, if the category is 1 and the prediction generated by the network (your sigmoid layer) is larger than 0.5, I count this as a correct prediction.  Similarly, when I see that the category is 0 and the prediction generated is smaller than 0.5, this is also correct.

```
correct = 0
for i in range(len(pairs[0])):
    output = model.predict([pairs[0][i][None], pairs[1][i][None]])[0][0]
    if (category[i] == 1 and output >= 0.5) or (category[i] == 0 and output < 0.5):
        correct += 1

print(correct / len(pairs[0]))
```

I get a 99.26% accuracy here, meaning that 0.74% out of 20000 samples, or about 148 samples were incorrectly classified.  I'd say that's a good result.

Reproducible Google Colab notebook can be found here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10Q6rjuiytRSump2nulW5UhXY_PJh1eor

Comment: Thank you, indeed the loss go down. As a side note, I tried manually writing two digits and comparing, and the results were off, meaning the generalization is not as good. Any suggestion on how to improve it?

Comment: @RodolfoDonãHosp Ah.  There are two ways.  (1) Introduce more scaling, rotation and translation in your training dataset and train on those. Hopefully with more examples that are different in scale, rotation and translation, we can generalize better. (2) Introduce images of your writing into the dataset.  The reason why it's so bad is because your writing is significantly different than the MNIST dataset, especially when it comes to scale and orientation of the digit.  Depending on what you think is more feasible, I can advise you further.

Comment: @RodolfoDonãHosp ... And most importantly, you MUST do the exact same preprocessing of your input images like you did with MNIST before inference in the network. Are you doing that?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I am doing the exact same preprocess, but what you said about generalizing the inputs sounds promising. Will switch the training process and introduce an ImageGenerator, hopefully it will improve the generalization. The test I didn't run with my own handwriting, instead I manually draw the same digit differently in Paint and manually made a pair of sames and differents

Comment: Ok. The two scales may be off. Remember that the MNIST digits occupy the entire image. There may be some slight scale issues. Try using an ImageGenerator and input in some scaling, rotation and translation to generalize the model. Glad I could help! Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: One last thing, the tesing i was doing is very different than yours. I put in the question what I was doing, but it was returning an array of two elements. In your test, using `model.predict([pairs[0][i][None], pairs[1][i][None]])` it returned a single number, the level of similarity. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you generated your pairs, it was a list of two elements where each element in the list contained a NumPy array of size `20000 x 28 x 28 x 1`.  20000 would be the # of samples.  Therefore, you create a list of two elements, each of size `1 x 28 x 28 x 1` so you represent one pair of images for testing.  All you have to do is change the first dimension of your `np.zeros` declaration from 2 to 1 (i.e.  `[np.zeros((1, INPUT_SHAPE[0], INPUT_SHAPE[1],INPUT_SHAPE[2])) for i in range(2)]`.  It's generating two probabilities because you are supplying a 2nd image pair that is blank for both images.